# getUserListStatuses where include retweets = false

Tags: java, twitter4j

Is there a reason the getUserListStatuses doesn't include a boolean to includeRetweets?  I know this is in the configuration, but what if I don't want to change my default configuration?  If I want a call specific config change, such as includeRetweets = false instead of true, is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks